# How to query the date of adding db to MySQL DBMS

Tags: mysql, metadata

MySQL provides many  cmds(queries) such as :

```
>SHOW DATABASE; 
>use <db> ; 
>
>select * From <t>;
.....
```

Is there a query that allow us to know what is the exactly date of adding database in DBMS . 
For example:

```
>SHOW datecreation <db>;
```

Does mySQL  support this feature? If no , What's the DBMS who can support

Answer (score 1):

as HAL9000 said, in current versions you can query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` for created date. For older versions that dont have `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` you can check the create date of the folder of your database in MySQL data dir.

By default it is in

`%ProgramData%\MySQL\MySQL Server <Your Version>\Data\<Your Database>` for windows,

and I believe

`/var/lib/mysql/<your database>` on *NIX.

Comment: Yeah, my second thoughts. +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

As for MySQL, you may try to dig some information from [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html) database:

```
SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES` WHERE `table_schema` = 'database-name';
-- information about tables in database
```

The oldest table there might give you suggestions when database was created.

As of databases, you may try query `SCHEMATA` table:

```
SELECT * FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`SCHEMATA`; -- information about databases
```

However it is not containing actual database creation time.